# upgrade helm chart upon patching one of its objects

Tags: kubernetes-cronjob

Do we need to explicitly  upgrade helm chart "Release-1"  when we do patch a particular object separately , for eg. Cron job "CJ1"?

In my case, I have patched cron job to run every min.
I did not however upgrade the helm chart that deployed the cron job.
"Kubectl get cj CJ1 -o yaml " although shows that the changes have been made from older schedule to the new schedule :- "* * * * *".

However the job is now not running at "* * * * *"

Answer (score 0):

When you say `patch` I presume you are referring to editing the object with `kubectl edit ...` or in any other way that apply the change without going through `helm upgrade` ?

Generally speaking if you follow DevOps and GitOps best practices any change you do should go through git (be version controlled). If you patch an object separately/manually then your code no longer represent what you have deployed, so the next time you upgrade the chart you are going to get the version without the patch (loose your changes).

So if you want to keep the changes that you have applied separately/manually then *Yes* ... change your code, then upgrade the chart.

If in the long term it doesn't matter and you are just playing around ... then you don't have to do anything as the change you want is already in Kubernetes.